# Change the picture depending on the screen size

Tags: php, html

I have a picture on my page

```
<div class="title-image">
     <img src="{{ $article->mainImage }}">
</div>
```

And let's say my mobile version starts when the screen size is less than 768px

And there should already be such a picture

```
<div class="title-image">
     <img src="{{ $article->mainImageMobile }}">
</div>
```

Is it possible to do this right here on the page so that the picture changes depending on the screen? Or do you just need to include css?

Comment: Using CSS would be a better approach to show responsive images.

Comment: If you are using CSS, the only two ways to create breakpoints are by writing them and embedding them inside of a `<style>` element in the HTML, or by declaring it in a linked stylesheet. You cannot set CSS breakpoints using inline styles. For a non-CSS approach, you can use the more modern `srcset` / `sizes` attributes for the image tag if you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achive this using css by playing with display block and none depending on the device size

HTML:

```
<div class="title-image">
     <img class="laptop" src="{{ $article->mainImage }}">
    <img class="mobile" src="{{ $article->mainImageMobile }}">

</div>
```

css:

```
.mobile{
  display:none;
}

@media only screen 
  and (max-width: 768px)
  {
    
    .laptop{
      display:none !important;
    }
    
    .mobile{
      display:block !important;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must already have different image sizes for this HTML.

```html
<img srcset="{{ $article->mainImageMobile }} 120w,
             {{ $article->mainImage }} 278w"
     sizes="(max-width: 710px) 120px,
            278px">
```

`srcset` is the set of images. Use unit in `w`.
`sizes` is set of media conditions.

Read more on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images), [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp).